# Missing Visual C# Projects Class Library

Tags: c#, dll

[image]I am trying to understand how to build a DLL with C#. Several examples are available on the web:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-C-Sharp-class-library-dll-using-visual-studio-net/

But each of them starts with:

Select File->New->Project->Visual C# Projects->Class Library

This is not available in my version of Visual Studio 2017 Community.
Is this normal?

Comment: Are you sure? Could you post the screenshot?

Comment: Id be surprised if they left out the template for a class library, are you sure its just not under a nested topic, is there a search in this dialog?

Comment: That tutorial is using Visual Studio .NET, which is *sixteen years old*.  The tutorial itself was posted in *2006*.  Find a newer tutorial.

Comment: I added a screenshot at top.
The example was last edited two weeks ago. I would love to have a better one.

Answer (score 0):

You might be lacking visual studio c# support. Open “Visual Studio installer,” and enable the “visual C#” checkbox, apply your changes and in a few minutes the templates you’re missing will be installed.

Comment: The screenshot at the top is what I have. C# is supported as far as I can tell.